# MOTD not displaying for LDAP users on Rocky 9 Linux

Tags: ldap, selinux, sshd, sssd, rocky-os

I have a Rocky 9.3 install configured to use `pam_access.so` and `pam_motd.so`. pam_access is working fine.  I'm running in to an issue where `/etc/motd` doesn't display for LDAP user logins but it does display for local account logins.

I'm using authselect.  I'm using a custom profile based on `sssd` with feature `with-pamaccess`.
selinux is set to permissive.
sshd_configs are set to `usePAM yes` and `PrintMotd no.`
`/etc/pam.d/sshd` is set to `session  optional  pam_motd.so`

I've tried enabling MOTD in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, pointing to a specifc non-standard motd, enabling `pam_motd.so` in `/etc/pam.d/login`.  I also enabled it in `/etc/authselect/system-auth`. All it does is print the MOTD additional times for every location i enabled it for local user logins but ldap user logins still have it suppressed.

`journalctl` log output did lead me to look at selinux for a bit since I was getting a warning regarding nfs home dirs even though they were mounting ok.  I told selinux about it `setsebool -P use_nfs_home_dirs 1` and the warnings went away.  As far as journalctl output is concerned, local and ldap user logins are now the same. so i don't think selinux has anything to do with it.

I'm not sure what else to try.  There's very little documentation on `pam_motd.so`.   TIA!

Update:  Turns out this isn't a PAM issue.  The issue remains even after taking PAM out of ssh login process.  I've updated the title and tags to reflect this but I kept the original body above for those who may suspect PAM in the beginning as well.
Now I'm looking at LDAP and sssd. little to nothing online on ldap and sssd with regards to motd.   `ssh -vvv` doesn't reveal anything.  only difference is one has motd output and the other doesn't.  I even used `strace` on the sshd service to see if there's a difference but still same output.

Comment: What does your entire `session` stack look like? Do you have any other modules that end the processing before pam_motd is reached? Does the distribution have `pamtester` available?

Comment: I wasn't aware of `pamtester`. thanks for that.  I was able to test with it and the motd displayed for the ldap users.  I back tracked and ended up stripping pam from the login process for ssh to see if pam really is the culprit.  with `usePAM no` and `PrintMotd yes` in sshd_config.  The motd is still not printed for ldap users.  To me this means pam_motd is actually doing what it's supposed to do.  Something else is suppressing the output.